# Property 'value' does not exist on type error in Vue3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, store, pinia

I tried to reference a variable of state through store, but an error occurs

```
import { AppState } from '@/types'
import { localStorage } from '@/utils/storage';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { getLanguage } from '@/lang/index';

const useAppStore = defineStore({
    id: 'appStore',
    state: (): AppState => ({
        device: 'desktop',
        language: getLanguage(),
    }),

    action: {
        setLanguage(language:string) {
            this.language = language;
            localStorage.set('language', language);
        },
    },
});

export default useAppStore;
```

Please check this attached image.
[image: Error image]

It's like a problem with typescript or settings. What's the problem?

Comment: I think the error come from your type `AppState`, typescript provide a dynamic typing you normally don't need to type this return function. Your example works fine for me, i don't get any errors, I just don't have your type `AppState`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out - https://runthatline.com/pinia-typescript-type-state-actions-getters/

Try adding type to your action and also check your AppState type

```
action: {
        setLanguage(language:string):void {
            this.language = language;
            localStorage.set('language', language);
        },
    },
```